# How to get the Index of second comma in a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, indexof

I have a string in an Array that contains two commas as well as tabs and white spaces. I'm trying to cut two words in that string, both of them before the commas, I really don't care about the tabs and white spaces.

My String looks similar to this:

```
String s = "Address1       Chicago,  IL       Address2     Detroit, MI"
```

I get the index of the first comma

```
int x = s.IndexOf(',');
```

And from there, I cut the string before the index of the first comma.

```
firstCity = s.Substring(x-10, x).Trim() //trim white spaces before the letter C;
```

So, how do I get the index of the second comma so I can get my second string?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Will the string always have 2 commas?

Comment: You want to start learning regex now.

Comment: why don't you `split(',')` and then get all slices in one array?

Comment: @shree.pat18 Good question. Sometimes it does and sometimes it does not have 2 commas.

Comment: [Get index of nth occurrence of char in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363083/get-index-of-nth-occurrence-of-char-in-a-string)

Comment: `s.Split(',').Skip(1).First()` could have done the job. No need to find indexes of characters.

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You have to use code like this.

```
int index = s.IndexOf(',', s.IndexOf(',') + 1);
```

You may need to make sure you do not go outside the bounds of the string though. I will leave that part up to you.

Answer (score 70):

I just wrote this Extension method, so you can get the nth index of any sub-string in a string.

Note: To get the index of the first instance, use `nth = 0`.

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int IndexOfNth(this string str, string value, int nth = 0)
    {
        if (nth < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Can not find a negative index of substring in string. Must start with 0");
        
        int offset = str.IndexOf(value);
        for (int i = 0; i < nth; i++)
        {
            if (offset == -1) return -1;
            offset = str.IndexOf(value, offset + 1);
        }
        
        return offset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

LastIndexOf gives you the Index of the last occurence of the given char / string.

```
int index = s.LastIndexOf(',');
```

Comment: Kindly add more details to your answer, explanations on how your code works and how this address the OP's question would be a great help not just for the asker but also for the future researchers.

Comment: this is not the second but the last