# Getting the second index of a spesific character in a string when only there is two of it

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need to get the index of a specific character in a string, but I need to know if it occurs twice in that string and if it is so, get the second occurrence index.
I tried a few things but couldn't find the solution.  Does anyone know how can it be done in .Net? Vb.net if possible.

What I am trying is explained below:

I have string like : 01298461705691703

I need to aquire the index of 17 in this string but if the string has two 17's then I need to know the index of the second one.

Comment: .IndexOf() will give you the position of the 1st occurrence, you can then use .IndexOf() again to look after that position for a 2nd occurrence.

Comment: So basically you want the index of the last occurrence?? I mean if you have 3 occurrences, you still want the second one? Or the last one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Index of second comma in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669044/how-to-get-the-index-of-second-comma-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is [String.LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
Dim myStr as String = "01298461705691703"
Dim idx as Integer = myStr.LastIndexOf("17")
```

or in c#

```
string myStr = "01298461705691703";
int idx = myStr.LastIndexOf("17");
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use `IndexOf` two times, using its overload on the second time.

```cs
string myStr = "01298461705691703";

// Find the first occurence
int index1 = myStr.IndexOf("17");
// You might want to check if index1 isn't -1

// Find the second occurrence, starting from the previous one
int index2 = myStr.IndexOf("17", index1 + 1);
// We add +1 so that it doesn't give us the same index again
// Result will be 13
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof

Answer (score 3):

Start your string from first occurrence `17`, something similar to

```
    string str = "01298461705691703";
    int i = str.IndexOf("17", s.IndexOf("17")+1);
                            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This will start your string from first occurrence of 17
```

Syntax of indexOf

[string.IndexOf(Char, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_IndexOf_System_Char_System_Int32_)

where,

- *char* is a unicode character to seek.
- *Int32* is starting index of string

---

If you are trying to find out last occurrence of `17` in string, then you can use [`string.LastIndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

```
    string str = "01298461705691703";
    int lastIndex = str.LastIndexOf("17");
```

---

POC : [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OeaC6f)