# C# substring after specific sign

Tags: c#, substring

how can I get a value of the string after last'/'

```
string path=http://localhost:26952/Images/Users/John.jpg
```

I would like to have as a result something like :
*John.jpg*

Comment: By finding the LastIndexOf() the /

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# third index of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578735/c-sharp-third-index-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: If you always want only the part after the last slash, you can use [String.LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: `LastIndexOf()`, and yeah this is probably a duplicate of 100 questions.

Comment: If you are looking at file names specifically, then you can use the Sysem.IO library. Call `var fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(path);`

Comment: Are you mainly looking for how to manipulate strings in general, or how to work with paths and file names? For string manipulation, look at the MSDN for String to see all the methods available. For path manipulation, look at the MSDN for System.IO.Path.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think using [`Path.GetFileName` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) is a better way instead of string manipulation.

```
string path = "http://localhost:26952/Images/Users/John.jpg";
var result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine(result); // John.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Split by '/' and get the last part:

```
 var url = "http://localhost:26952/Images/Users/John.jpg";
 var imageName = url.Split('/').Last();
```